# is it safe to recv passing in 0 to detect a socket error?

Tags: c++, sockets

For a TCP blocking socket, is it safe to call:

```
if(SOCKET_ERROR != recv(s, NULL, 0, 0))
//...
```

to detect errors?

I thought it was safe, then I had a situation on a computer that it was hanging on this statement.  (was with an ssl socket if that matters).  I also tried passing in the MSG_PEEK flag with a buffer specified but I also had a hang there.

What is the alternative?

Comment: I am on Windows if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to other answers - here's a handy little function to get the pending socket error:

```
/* Retrives pending socket error. */
int get_socket_error( int sockfd )
{
    int error;
    socklen_t len( sizeof( error ));

    if ( getsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len ) < 0 )
        error = errno;

    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did say you were using a blocking socket, but you should use select instead (even if you set it unblocking before the select call).  It allows you to poll a file descriptor and see if there is data waiting, or if there is an error.

Answer (score 2):

The call itself is "safe" in a sense that it should work as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121%28VS.85%29.aspx), however you must realize that `recv` is a blocking receive call.  This means that the call will block the executing thread until data arrives on the socket.  This can cause your application to "hang" if you are not using a different thread to do your receive, or checking to see if data is available before call receive ([select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28VS.85%29.aspx)).